# Is it legal to use “VirtualBox” software without making a payment?

Tags: open-source-software

I am planning to open a blog webpage, publish technology-based content on it and make money via blogger earning methods like Google AdSense.

The software I mentioned in the title, which is available at [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/), is just one of the necessities to prepare my content.

However, firstly, I want to be sure whether this kind of usage is legal or not for this free software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ), the VirtualBox base package is licensed under the GPL. That means you're free to use it for any purpose. The VirtualBox Extension Pack has a more restrictive license, which is only free for personal, educational, or evaluation use.

Comment: So, I understand that I can do what I asked in my question with the packages provided on [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) page titled as "VirtualBox 6.1.4 platform packages". Is that correct?

Comment: @NetworkingFan That's correct.